# Eval already loaded script tag

Tags: javascript, eval

I have the following code

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <title></title>
            <script type='text/javascript' src="js.js" id="scripter"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
<button>AGAIN</button>
    </body>
    </html>
```

The included js has as set of statements whichg gets executed as soon as the page load.
*** NOTE : it does not contain any function and dont want to contain any function.

On click of the button AGAIN i want to eval the entire script once again. Any possible ways this can be done ??

Trying to get the script contents of the script included so that I can eval it.
Any possible ways this can be achieved ??

OR

Some other method to achieve the same ??

Thanks.

For people downvoting this : I know those are what functions are for, hence specified note specifically. Maybe I should have asked the latter part of the question directly wtihout giving much details. Is it possible for me to access the scripts content that gets included in a page ??

Comment: Why *not* just use a function? That's exactly what they're for, repeatable code.

Comment: I know those are what functions are for, hence specified note specifically. Maybe I should have asked the latter part of the question directly without giving too many details. Is it possible for me to access the scripts content that gets included in a page ??

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved by setting `<script>`'s `src` attribute to the same with a random get variable like

```
scriptTag.src = scriptTag.src + "?r=" + Math.random();
```

which will cause the browser to load the entire file again and that's usually not a good idea, but that's how it could be done

Answer (score 0):

I dont know how big that JS file of yours is but - if its possible - you can write that file as

```
$someVariable = ' Whole Javascript code in quotes';
```

And whenever you want to run the code again just call  eval($someVariable).

Now you might have a question for me. How is it gunna run at the very first time.
just add following line at the end of your JS file.

```
eval($someVariable);
```